# Remove /boot partition

Tags: boot, partitioning

Sometimes I wanted to do smart partitions, by doing **separate /boot partition**, but I only give little space. Now I am having problems with lack of space on that partition.

How to remove /boot partition and join it with /root partition?

Comment: Have you thought to clean out older kernels from /boot before you try merging it with the / filesystem?

Comment: yeah, but it's some "public" pc, so I don't want to do this each few months... (ok I know I could, but still...)

Comment: See my answer below -- you could also resize the partition, instead of changing your partitioning scheme (which is a good one)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `cp -a /boot /boot-tmp` to copy the contents to a temporary directory on the root filesystem, unmount the boot partition using `umount /boot`, and put the files back in place with `rmdir /boot && mv /boot-tmp /boot`.

Once you verify that everything is fine you can remove `/boot` from `/etc/fstab`. Finally, you should double-check the GRUB configuration and run `update-grub`.

Comment: Probably want to make sure `/etc/fstab` is correct once you do this.

Comment: I'd like to reiterate though that increasing the size of the boot partition is probably a better choice ... I don't understand why you wouldn't just want to do that ...

Comment: @jrtayloriv: Would you care to elaborate why a separate boot partition is preferable? -- I read in some ancient guide, 100 MB for a boot partition would be ok. Now `apt-get upgrade` regularly fails because of insufficient disk space. I don't want to move partitions. Do you know a solution that would automatically purge ancient kernels?

Comment: I have tried this, but my system somehow appears to load the configuration from the (now not mounted anymore) boot partition. (I have changed `/etc/default/grub`, and run `update-grub`, but the changes were not reflected in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.) Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

You could also just keep the /boot partitition and expand it with [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/). (Of course, as always, backup first and keep a liveCD handy in case something goes wrong)

If you've never resized partitions before, there are plenty of tutorials on the web that will tell you how to do it. Here's a good tutorial to start with: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-resizing-partitions-1/index.html

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I rather just join in "/" partition. I would need to resize other partitions also....

Comment: If that's the case, you can "merge" partitions using gparted as well. Move the files from /boot partition to / partition. Then set bootloader to boot from the new /boot directory of the root partition. If everything works, and it boots up properly, then delete the boot partition and resize the other partitions to fill the space. Again -- make backups and keep a livecd ready (and I'll reiterate that resizing is probably a much better and easier solution than merging ...)

Comment: I've been reading a lot about how to increase the size of a separate boot partition. In my case I have only SSH/terminal access to the linux box and I have to say it sounds *really* scary! It requires deleting my data-filled partition, `dd`-ing the partition-less filesystem contents to a new position on disk, then recreating the partition over the new location of those contents. It feels like I'm McGyver-ing things around with paper clips and duct tape! Moving the contents of the boot partition into the root one looks like a much better choice IMO.