# My boot partition is filling up. What's the solution?

Tags: boot, partitioning

How do I know what is safe to remove?  Can I make the partition larger without damaging data in that or adjacent partitions?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I had the same problem.

This q&a fixed it for me.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/334976/safe-to-remove-old-kernels-after-installing-latest-mainline

Answer (score 0):

You can boot the livecd and use `gparted` to resize it, or [remove it](https://askubuntu.com/q/30130/8500) instead.

Comment: Thanks Gracchus, Are you suggesting that I run the code in a terminal?  What would be the result?  Psusi Thanks for letting me know that's safe, but as to "removing it," are you suggesting that I remove the partition and make my home and boot partitions 1?

Comment: @hortstu, unless you have a very unusual system you don't need a /boot partition at all and so you can follow the instructions in the linked question to move the /boot directory to your / partition, which is where it normally lives for everyone who doesn't create a dedicated partition for it.

Comment: Thanks again.  I was under the impression that giving boot a dedicated partition makes life easier when you switch from one LTS version to another.  I have my drive partitioned in order to keep data boot and home separate. By the time the next LTS comes out I'll be done with the old boot partition and I can clean it out and install the new one.  So I'm always running a dual boot with the 2 latest ubuntu LTS versions.  If this isn't necessary please explain if you don't mind. Thanks.

Comment: @hortstu, you don't need a /boot partition to dual boot.  Reasons to need one are 1) your bios can't see the whole drive, or 2) you want to use an exotic root filesystem that the boot loader does not understand.