# Stuck in grub. Cannot boot anything

Tags: grub2, reinstall

I was having a problem with my wifi on Linux and went through every suggestion i could find and nothing worked so i decided to try and uninstall and reinstall linux. After i uninstalled and restarted. It gave me the grub page. I have looked at about 10 different answers to similar questions but nothing has helped. I have the ubuntu dvd ready to install but can't figure out how to get out of grub.

Comment: Delete your boot section on your Hard disk

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: Use live disk to load into ubuntu and [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30130/remove-boot-partition)

Comment: I have the disk but it only goes to the grub page

Comment: you should setup your boot priorities in BIOS

Comment: How do i do that? I'm very new at this

Comment: you need to put you cd-rom to be the first place BIOS tries to boot from [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Again. I know how to install it. I already had it on my computer. I was trying to uninstall and reinstall it but after uninstall it now i can only see a "grub" page when i turn the computer on. I have the disk to install ubuntu again but nothing i do gets me out of the grub page.