# How to remove separate /boot partition on UEFI system?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

When installing Ubuntu, I have created a separate `/boot` partition for no good reason. Now I'd like to use that partition for something else and move my boot files to the main partition.

I tried the steps from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/30131/129094), but now my system boots into GRUB's prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/30131/129094) is a good starting point, but it's not sufficient on UEFI systems.

Here's a step-by-step guide which worked for me.

This answer assumes following partition names:

```
Device      Purpose
-------------------------
/dev/sda2   EFI partition
/dev/sda5   /boot
/dev/sda6   /
```

A bootable media (live USB etc.) with Ubuntu or some other Linux distribution is required. **Make backups before following these steps.**

1. Boot from Ubuntu media and open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Become root:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
2. Mount filesystems of `/`, `/boot` and the EFI partition:

   ```
   cd /mnt
   mkdir efi boot os
   mount /dev/sda2 efi
   mount /dev/sda5 boot
   mount /dev/sda6 os
   ```
3. Copy contents of the `/boot` partition into `/boot` directory on `/` partition:

   ```
   cp -r boot/* os/boot
   ```
4. Prevent Ubuntu from mounting `/boot` automatically. Also take note of root partition's UUID. Open `/etc/fstab` in your preferred editor:

   ```
   gedit os/etc/fstab
   ```

   Here's what mine looked like (save for comments):

   ```
   UUID=df89aab6-941d-4ffa-9681-e16fc94641d3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
   UUID=f7c32b17-a2f1-4eb3-a8e7-414b6a228a72 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
   UUID=2252-1B80  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
   UUID=a80bb662-d531-408b-bc23-b47f28c44ec4 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
   /swapfile   none    swap    sw  0   0
   ```

   I have commented out the second line which mounts `/boot`. I have also copied UUID of `/` partition, we'll need that in a moment.
5. Update GRUB's configuration on the EFI partition. *This step is crucial on UEFI systems.*

   ```
   cd /mnt/efi/EFI/ubuntu
   cp grub.cfg grub.cfg.bak
   gedit grub.cfg
   ```

   My `grub.cfg` looked like this:

   ```
   search.fs_uuid f7c32b17-a2f1-4eb3-a8e7-414b6a228a72 root hd1,gpt5 
   set prefix=($root)'/grub'
   configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
   ```

   I had to update: 1. the UUID, 2. the partition number and 3. the prefix. Modified file looks like this:

   ```
   search.fs_uuid df89aab6-941d-4ffa-9681-e16fc94641d3 root hd1,gpt6 
   set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
   configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
   ```

   Note that it's the same UUID I got from `/etc/fstab` and I had to prepent `/boot` to the prefix.
6. Reboot into Ubuntu on your hard disk. It should boot just fine. Make sure `/boot` isn't mounted - `grep /boot /etc/mtab` should output nothing. Format the old `/boot` partition (don't confuse it with current `/boot`, which is a regular directory) and refresh GRUB config:

   ```
   sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda5
   sudo update-grub
   ```
7. Reboot once more, confirm that the OS is up and do whatever you want with your ex-boot partition.