# Grub menu broken after deleting one version of Ubuntu, boot repair for other Ubuntu fails

Tags: boot, grub2

I was running three operating systems, Windows 10, Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and Ubuntu 18.04. As I didn't need Ubuntu anymore, I formated that partition, realizing too late that that may cause problems with the grub.
Now when booting I only get to the grub terminal.
I tried booting from a live USB and running Boot Repair, but that only told ma to run it from a live USB to enable the repair tool (but I was running it on a live USB). However, it was able to create an URL with the date it analysed, wich is:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BJjRNqy9sb/

I also tried a the live version of just the Boot Repair, but it doesn't seem to run, it gets to the loadscreen just fine, but afterwards I only get a black screen.

Thanks in advance to everyone trying to help me with this.

Comment: Report does not yet show all the details on NVMe drives. But always best to run Boot-Repair from Ubuntu live installer. The Boot-Repair ISO is older and may not support newer systems. In advanced mode you can select the full reinstall of grub. Or you  can manually edit /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg (from install) and where ever it mounts with live installer. That should have UUID & partition of your install, not older install. Example here #5: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001426/how-to-remove-separate-boot-partition-on-uefi-system

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by installing Ubuntu 19.10 on a different partition, which then - during it's installation - did repair and update the grub.

Answer (score 0):

You chose not to let `boot-repair` fix your boot. If you do choose to let `boot-repair` make changes it will do this:

```
=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of nvme0n1p7, using the following options:       nvme0n1p1/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot use-standard-efi-file


=================== Blockers in case of suggested repair
Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This will enable this feature.


=================== Final advice in case of suggested repair
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on nvme0n1p1/efi/.../grub*.efi file!

If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\...\grub*.efi


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.
```

Comment: I did try to use the recommended repair option, but it said that I had to run boot repair on a live usb to be able to use that option (I was running it on a live usb)

Comment: There is an option to email the boot-repair developers with problems like that.

Comment: Problems may have originated by 18.04 using Grub 2.02 and 19.10 using Grub 2.04: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GRUB-2.04-Released

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to me, I had:

- Ubuntu 16.04 on an HDD (*sda*)
- Windows on an SSD (*sdb*)
- Another Ubuntu 16.04 on *sdb*, but grub was loaded in *sda*.

After I removed my Ubuntu version from *sda*, I could only get to grub terminal, and booting from an Ubuntu USB and running boot-repair didn't solve anything.

Solved it by installing Ubuntu 16.04 again in my HDD, which during installation repaired the grub.