# how can I boot to sda2 and not sda4

Tags: boot

when I restart my computer, it boots to ubuntu 18.10 on sda4.  I don't want that.  I want to boot to 18.04 on sda2.  I can do this by selecting from the list of oses during the boot process, but if i have a power outage, it boots to the wrong os.  What to do?

```
Model: ATA WDC WD1001FALS-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   537GB   536GB   ext4
 3      537GB   537GB   1049kB                                     bios_grub
 4      537GB   1000GB  464GB   ext4

jcg@jcg-hp:/boot$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64
[sudo] password for jcg: 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-041500rc6-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-041500rc6-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-72-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-70-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-70-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-31-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Ubuntu 18.10 (18.10) on /dev/sda4
done
Processing triggers for shim-signed (1.37~18.04.3+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1) ...
EFI variables are not supported on this system
/sys/firmware/efi/efivars not found, aborting.
jcg@jcg-hp:/boot$
```

Comment: I imagine that 18.10 is first in grub order, but you want 18.04 to be first.  Can try updating grub in 18.04, if that does not work, can do a google search on how to adjust grub order.

Comment: @ Doug Smythies  Most bios will only choose which drive is first booted, not which partition on a drive( the few I know of).

Comment: I can't seem to get bios to change this.  In Grub Customizer I don't seem to have any entries for 18.04, just 18.10 (sda4).  The way I boot is from list that shows up during boot process

Comment: Bios won't,  have you tried ```sudo update-grub``` when you are in 18.04.

Comment: yes, just did that.. no change

Comment: Are you saying that if you choose 18.04 in grub you still boot to 18.10?

Comment: if i choose 18.04 i get 18.04, but I can't make it the default

Comment: Can check this link, quite a lot of info.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order

Comment: Need to see output of `sudo parted -l` and `gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: I think /boot/grub/grub.cfg is too long to post

Comment: The 18.04 update-grub does nothing but rewrite the (unused) grub.cfg.  Run sudo grub-install /dev/sda  from 18.04 to fix that.  (Or just copy the 18.04 to the 18.10 location) Assuming you are booting legacy.

Comment: You need to edit /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. You may have to reset permissions or use live installer. Or totally reinstall grub from 18.04. Only one Ubuntu version is default in UEFI. Even renaming does not work, but I have not tested with 2.04, yet. Try this also: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054032/grub-loads-instead-of-ubuntu-whenever-my-hp-streambook-reboots Shows 3 line grub.cfg in ESP: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001426/how-to-remove-separate-boot-partition-on-uefi-system

Comment: I can't get to that file but I did run dpkg-reconfigure.. see updated question

Comment: You could start by doing what oldfred suggests - `sudo gedit /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`. Alter the UUID to that of **sda2** and followed by `root hd0,gpt2` then save and reboot. If you get a black screen with a grub prompt it's easily fixed from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the grub timeout and the grub default boot entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry)